# What is the Difference between ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper and ReadOnlyIntegerProperty?

Tags: javafx

When to use which one? 
If it called ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper then why still we could change the value of it? Here is example.

```
import javafx.beans.property.*;
public class ReadOnlyCheck{
    public static void main(String... args){
        ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper idWrapper = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(100);
        ReadOnlyIntegerProperty id = idWrapper.getReadOnlyProperty();
        System.out.println("idWrapper:" + idWrapper.get());
        System.out.println("id:" + id.get());
        // Change the value
        idWrapper.set(101);
        System.out.println("idWrapper:" + idWrapper.get());
        System.out.println("id:" + id.get());
    }
}
```

So I want to ask what is the difference between them.

**Edited:**

if ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper also can change the value then what is the use of SimpleIntegerProperty() ? why they introduced ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper?

Comment: `ReadOnlyIntgerProperty` cannot be changed after initialization *(not how [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyIntegerProperty.html) mentions no setter-method)* whereas `ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper` can

Comment: @specializt why wrapper can? then what is the use of SimpleIntegerProperty(); ?

Comment: ... what? Could you please ask someone who speaks english to help you translate?

Comment: @specializt I mean if ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper also can change the value then what is the use of SimpleIntegerProperty() ? why they introduced ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper?

Answer (score 3):

ReadOnlyIntegerProperty is the super class of ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.

So ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper is ReadOnlyIntegerProperty with the additional behaviour that it is a convenient class to define read-only properties. It creates two properties that are synchronized. One property is read-only and can be passed to external users. The other property is read- and writable and should be used internally only.

Comment: But when to use this class? what is the advantages?

Comment: the first one can be used via @FXML bindings hence inside of FXML files and scenegraphs, the second one is extremely useful for internal JavaFX-aware code which needs to manipulate the value and have it read-only visible to external classes, for example

Answer (score 3):

`SimpleIntegerProperty` is a class property that allows the user to read and write a value. Sometimes however you do want to restrict write access to the data. In this case a `ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyWrapper` can be used. This property can be modified, but also allows you to provide a readonly view of the property. Simply returing `SimpleIntegerProperty` from a property method with return type `ReadOnlyIntegerProperty` does not ensure the property is not writeable, since the user of that class could still cast it to `IntegerProperty` and use the result of the cast to set the property

Consider these 2 versions of the `Counter` class

```
public class Counter {

    private final SimpleIntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public void increment() {
        value.set(value.get() + 1);
    }

    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty valueProperty() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Counter {

    private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper value = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();

    public void increment() {
        value.set(value.get() + 1);
    }

    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty valueProperty() {
        return value.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
}
```

```
Counter c = new Counter();
c.valueProperty().addListener((a,b, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue));
c.increment();
((IntegerProperty)c.valueProperty()).set(-5);
c.increment();
```

works with the first version of the class and yields a `ClassCastException`, if the second version is used.

Comment: `ReadOnlyIntegerProperty can be used. This property can be modified,` sure ? how? Then what is the use of this property?

Comment: @Nothing Sorry, forgot the `Wrapper` part there

Answer (score 0):

I picked the example below from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/148421143X).

```
@Override
public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception {
    ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper idWrapper = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(100);
    ReadOnlyIntegerProperty id = idWrapper.getReadOnlyProperty();

    System.out.println("idWrapper.get() = " + idWrapper.get());
    System.out.println("id.get() = " + id.get());

    idWrapper.set(10);

    System.out.println("idWrapper.get() = " + idWrapper.get());
    System.out.println("id.get() = " + id.get());
}
```

As we can see, the `ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper` is read/write property, but the `ReadOnlyIntegerProperty` is only a read property.
When we write a new value to the `idWrapper` property, the value of the `id` is also updated(synchronized).

So why we should use one in place of the other, the authors of the book add this explanation:

> Typically, a wrapper property is used as private instance variable of
>   a class. The class can change the property internally. One of its
>   methods returns the read-only property of the wrapper class, so the
>   same property is read-only for the outside world.

a Tiny example to make it clear

```
class Person{
    private ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper wealth = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();

    /*We return the read-only property of the wrapper class*/
    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty getWealth() {
        return wealth.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    private void setWealth(int newValue){
        //here, internally we can write a new value to the wealth property. 
    }
}
```